# SimpleITK Windows Universal App - does not build in release, strange behaviour in debugging and TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, itk

**TL;DR version: `Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef` while trying to use SimpleITK on Universal Windows App.**

So, right now I have to make simple school project using SimpleITK, and, I got interested in new Universal Windows Applications. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

So, I created a sample project, added references to SimpleITKManaged, copy&pasted SimpleITKNative to obj/Debug catalog and tried to do some tutorials. However, I learned that mixing two new technologies together may be a bad idea.

The ITK libraries I use seem not to work with Universal Windows App. After putting this snippet anywhere in the code, I can not get to debug the method. Code is not hitting breakpoint at the beggining of the method. What is inside is not important, as any type from SimpleITK is causing code to fail.

```
private void TestMethod()
{//breakpoint here
    ImageFileReader reader = new ImageFileReader();
    reader.SetFileName(FileName);
    var image = reader.Execute();
}
```

The exception seems to be thrown before code gets to method, probably at level of XAML. I tried first implementing a call as ICommand, then as event handler in the code behind, with no differences. The exception is also not too helpful:

```
 Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

Neither is StackTrace:

```
at Pomwjo.Universal.MainPage.ButtonBase_OnClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

The same libraries work well in WPF. I tried both x64 and x86 libraries, with the same problem. The build target and library architecture are matching. I'm using **SimpleITK C# x86 wrapper 0.9.0, compiled with .NET v2.0.50727, using ITK 4.7.2**. I got them pre-built from Sourceforge.  Just after that, I found a 0.9.1 version, which I downloaded and tried to use it, to no avail.

Next step was *ok, I'm a pro programmer - I'll build it myself!*. I will spare describing what it is to build a huge library, let's just say it didn't work either.

Any ideas, how to fix this problem?

**EDIT 1**
I just realized, that if code is unreachable, it doesn't complain. Well, at least that is working as expected. But, what is even stranger, this snippet fails only if condition is met:

```
  if (new Random().Next(1, 10)%2 == 0)
       WrapperMethod(); //inside is snippet from above.
  else  return;
```

Also, when building in release, I get this error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(791,7): error : MCG0024: MCG0024:UnresolvableTypeReference Unresolvable type reference 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef' in 'Assembly(Name=mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)' found. Check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Windows Universal Apps. From my brief reading on it, it seems to be sand boxed and restrict access to certain system libraries and components. The SimpleITK Native library likely does not meet these requirements. Could the be the cause of the error you are receiving? If there are build issues, I can address those. Make sure you are doing the Superbuild.

Comment: If by build issues you understand building ITK, then no, there are none. What is Superbuild, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this question was first written, it was impossible to use simpleITK in Universal Apps because it lacked some of classes required for it to work - including `System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef`.

Also, because all apps are run in sandbox, my guess (educated, but still guess) is that it is downright impossible to use native C++ code which is used  by SimpleITK. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx) describes a way to import native code into app, however this would require quite a bit of tinkering around ITK libraries itself - which was not a point in my project.